# Why next.js throws an error if I delete loading.tsx file from app directory?

Tags: next.js

I have a simple next.js app, where in app folder there is a loading.tsx file

```
// loading.tsx
import React from 'react'

function Loading() {
  return (
    <h1>loading...</h1>
  )
}

export default Loading
```

but if I delete it, the error occurs:

```
Error: Failed to read source code from "my directory"
Caused by:
    No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I tried stopping my localhost and deleting next folder in my project. The error was gone, is there any other way of fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has also popped up on the NextJS discord.

If you delete the loading.tsx file (at any level, including nested segments), you will need to stop the server and delete the `.next`.

Deleting the `.next` directory locally is a harmless task.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is because there might be a reference to the `loading.tsx` file in your other configuration files. When you delete the file, Next.js is unable to find it and throws an error.

I would suggest to remove or update the reference in other files.